# setInterval - running second function after another

Tags: javascript

I have created a script to run on the console log for our monitor datastudio dashboard report which consists of two pages. What I am trying to do is to automatically navigate between these two pages using next and previous button.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".navBtn.preBtn").click();
  },30000)
  $(".navBtn.nextBtn").click();
},30000)
```

The auto navigation worked but I noticed that the interval is not fixed. It's supposed to wait for 30 seconds before running the second function but in this case, the interval between running the functions is random.

Comment: Is the navigation leaving the page? Once the page is reloaded the interval will clear and start over.

Comment: Yes, the report goes to its second page (nextBtn.click) but then it immediately goes back to the first page of the report (preBtn.click) instead of waiting for 30 seconds before executing the $(".navBtn.preBtn").click() function again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not fixed. It will run your callback after "at least" specified time. Your callback is added to a queue which is getting processed when the stack is empty. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop.

Comment: So what's the correct way to achieve the functionality that I need?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded language, so it's a challenging task .A polling strategy with setInterval() can do well, but it is still depends of the stack. For example: it can poll at inteval of 1s and compare time, when it's time - clear interval and call the callback.